# docker entrypoint no such file or directory

Tags: docker, entry-point

I am building a docker image. I want the image to run automatically a program I add to the image, so I'm trying to use ENTRYPOINT, without success.

My dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM archlinux

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

ADD app /usr/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/app", "-s" "/scene/scene.json", "-c", "/scene/simulator.json", "--headless", "1", "-t"]
CMD ["0"]
```

When I try to run it, I get the following output

```
docker run --gpus all --name app_deploy -v /scene:/scene -it app_image
0: [/usr/bin/app,: No such file or directory
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a comma missing?

```
 "-s" "/scene/scene.json"
     ^
     Insert comma here
```

Comment: that happens to everyone…